# Looking for suggestions to host CI server

Tags: continuous-integration

I am part of team with remote developers.For subversion,we are using online hosting service of a website.Now,we want to setup Hudson as CI for our project.Can you suggest me how can I go about it? Is there a site offering this service?,Or,should I take some windows hosting account and install?

Answer (score 0):

I know about this one [CI Foundry](http://cifoundry.net/)

I'm sure there are others.